# allow only numbers in input text box

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to create simple validation form, which allows only numbers, for example, if i write into input field 223w i want to console.log('error, write only number'), I can not figure out what happens here, i am new in js…

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="inputs mt-4" id="with_cash">
    <input id="inpt" type="text" placeholder="enter only number" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
const test = document.getElementById('inpt')

var extest = test.value

var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

var regex2 = /^[0-9]+$/;

//thats not works correctly
withCash.addEventListener('input', function () {

    if (!extest.match(regex)) {
        console.log('error write only number')

    } else if (!extest.match(regex2)) {
        console.log('must input number')
        return false;
    }

})
```

Comment: What's `withCash` variable? Is it an input? You have syntax errors in your code. Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

- read about [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- create a regexp that accepts only numbers `/^\d+$/`
- in event handler test input value by the regexp `regexp.test(value)`

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const onlyNumbersRegExp = /^\d+$/;

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (onlyNumbersRegExp.test(input.value)) {
    console.log('only numbers');
  } else {
    console.log('not only numbers');
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="enter only number" />
```